# What is the remainder?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What is the remainder when $7^{2002}+3^{2002}+2002$ is divided by $29$ ?

I tried out the problem using congruent modulo but cannot help my cause.

Comment: To start, raise 7 to consecutive powers 1, 2, 3, ..., and find the remainder in division by 29. Do you see a pattern?

Answer (score 5):

Hint: $7^2 + 3^2 = 2 \cdot29$.

Comment: the answer is 1....gt it as 2002 is 1 mod 29....thank you so much..

Answer (score 3):

These kind of problems can always be solved in a similar matter. The goal is to find powers that are congruent $1$ or $-1$ modulo $29$. So you start with $7$ and calculate it's powers modulo $29$:
$$\begin{align*}
7^1&\equiv 7\\
7^2&\equiv 7\cdot 7\equiv 49 \equiv 20\\
7^3&\equiv 20\cdot 7\equiv 140\equiv 24\\
7^3&\equiv 24\cdot 7\equiv 168\equiv 23\\
7^3&\equiv 23\cdot 7\equiv 161\equiv 16\\
&\vdots\\
7^7&\equiv 25\cdot 7\equiv 175\equiv 1
\end{align*}$$
The same for powers of $3$ gives you $3^{14}\equiv 28\equiv -1$. Since $1^k\equiv 1$ and $(-1)^{2k}\equiv 1$ for all $k\in\mathbb Z$, you can reduce the exponent of $7$ modulo $7$ (i.e. $2002\equiv 0\mod 7$) and the exponent of $3$ modulo $28$ (i.e. $2002\equiv 14\mod 28$ and $3^{14}\equiv -1\mod 29$). Now you are left with $1-1+2002$. All you need to do is calculate the remainder of $2002$.

If you know a little number theory you can even use Fermat's little theorem $a^{p-1}\equiv 1\mod p$ to begin with and reduce all exponents modulo $28$, or only try divisors of $28$ to find smaller exponents giving $1$ or $-1$.

Answer (score 2):

Every element in $Z_{29}$ has order DIVIDING 28 (Multiplicative order). $2002\cong 1 \mod 29$. Does that help?

Comment: So for example $7^{28}\cong 1 \mod 29$.

Comment: @Luis may I point you to an old discussion (came across it myself a couple of days ago)? http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/415/homework-questions-avoiding-giving-a-complete-solution

Comment: @JonathanY. Thank you. Sorry, I am new to this website. I am having a difficult time giving "hints" that are not too much. But thank you

Comment: I guess a beter hint could be "use Fermat's little theorem"

Comment: For my taste, that's giving it away (as the question clearly deals with understanding the workings of that very theorem).

Comment: What would you suggest?

Comment: Something more along the lines of what @Maesumi and njguliyev wrote, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

You have $2002 \equiv 14$ modulo $28 = \varphi(29)$. Recall Euler's theorem: $$7^{2002} \equiv 7^{14} = 7^{(29 - 1)/2} = \Big( \frac{7}{29}\Big) = 1,$$ since $7 \equiv 36 = 6^2$ is a square mod $29$.

On the other hand, $3$ is not a square mod $29$, since $$\Big( \frac{3}{29} \Big) = \Big( \frac{29}{3} \Big) = \Big( \frac{2}{3} \Big) = -1$$ using quadratic reciprocity.

In all, you get $$7^{2002} + 3^{2002} + 2002 \equiv 1 + (-1) + 2002 \equiv 2002 \equiv 1 \; (\bmod 29).$$